# Help please with correct saving multiselect field for Store view edit form

Tags: magento2, custom, store-view, multiselect

Please help with correct saving adding custom field for Store View edit form.

Default Magento Store view edit form:

> Stores->All Stores->Any Store

- https://screencast.com/t/WPA3owq3
- https://screencast.com/t/2t3Bg9vYizH0

Here is the way how I have added custom field:

using observer (subscribed on the **adminhtml_store_edit_form_prepare_form** event via `adminhtml/events.xml`) and

added field https://screencast.com/t/bUow3hzc73Aq  In the admin part new field has been added successfully, BUT I have trouble with multiple values sending (event if I select couple values, anyway magento SENDS ONLY ONE value - https://www.screencast.com/t/GOyaXm1m).

Please Help me on this  I fighting on this issue more than 2 days already.
Maybe anybody knows about any existing restriction for Store View edit form?

Comment: Can you remove value and then check.

Comment: Removed value, unfortunately it doesn`t help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution, how could be send couple values
https://screencast.com/t/RWjZYejJV2